# java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection, multipartform-data

getting issue when writing large video file using httpurlconnection.

```
java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on Connection{192.1.4.55, proxy=DIRECT@ hostAddress=192.1.4.55 cipherSuite=none protocol=http/1.1} (recycle count=0)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection.readResponse(HttpConnection.java:210)W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpTransport.readResponseHeaders(HttpTransport.java:80)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readNetworkResponse(HttpEngine.java:904)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:788)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:443)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:388)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:501)
```

response code is here

```
final InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
            final ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            final byte[] buffer = new byte[maxBufferSize];
            int bytesRead;
            while ((bytesRead = is.read(buffer, 0, 1024)) != -1) {
                bytes.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
            log.log(INFO,
                    format("{0} took {4} ms", url,
                            (currentTimeMillis() - start)));
            String response = new String(bytes.toByteArray());
```

Comment: long processes should be moved to separate thread

Comment: The server unexpectedly closed the connection instead of sending a response. Are you sure the request was valid HTTP?

Comment: yes, its working perfectly for file size<5MB. but throwing above error when file size is large.

Comment: So the server is imposing a size limit.

Comment: actually we uploading files to server and then server writing those files to another server. so its taking much time.

Comment: I don't see what the time taken has to do with it. The server is still imposing a size limit.

Comment: I am getting same error..what u have done to solve this?? if you solved the issue please post your answer.

Comment: I think @EJP got a good point, probably the server is having some size limit...

Answer (score 3):

Check it if you are using OkHttpClient, here is a parameter retryOnConnectionFailure(false). By default it is false, you just make it true then error will be removed. Hopefully because I have same problem and solve just change it.

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .retryOnConnectionFailure(true)
    .build();
```

Answer (score -3):

Please use BufferedInputStream and BufferedOutputStream to buffer the data for larger files

Answer (score -3):

Hope this Code will Help you .

```
BufferedReader br = null;
if (conn.getResponseCode() == 200) {
    Log.e("HTTP success code", "" + conn.getResponseCode());
    InputStream inputStream = conn.getInputStream();
    if (inputStream != null)
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
} else {
    Log.e("HTTP error code", "" + conn.getResponseCode());
    InputStream inputStream = conn.getErrorStream();
    if (inputStream != null)
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
} 
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
String output;
while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
    builder.append(output);
}
Log.e(reqTag + " Response :", builder.toString());
conn.disconnect();
```

Answer (score -6):

Sometimes this exception can be ignore,you may need to retry.
e.g. use charles proxy you mobile phone wifi,download file,charles Terminate this connection,you will receive same exception.